# Create sequence in R

Tags: r, sequence

Hi I was wondering if someone knows how to realize this sequence in         R?

```
Consider a sequence with following requirement.
a1=1
an=an-1+3 (If n is a even number)
an=2×an-1-5 (If n is a odd number)
   e.g. 1,4,3,6,7,10,15,...

   a30=?
```

Comment: It is not clear whether you are doing it recursively

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.
It will return the entire sequence, not just the last element.

```
seq_chih_peng <- function(n){
    a <- integer(n)
    a[1] <- 1
    for(i in seq_along(a)[-1]){
        if(i %% 2 == 0){
            a[i] <- a[i - 1] + 3
        }else{
            a[i] <- 2*a[i - 1] - 5
        }
    }
    a
}

seq_chih_peng(30)
```

Note that I do not include code to check for input errors such as passing `n = 0` or a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it recursively, you just have the write the equations in your function as follows:

```
sequence <- function(n) {
  if (n == 1) return(1)
  else if (n > 1) {
    if (n %% 2 == 1) {
      return(2 * sequence(n - 1) - 5)
    }else{
     return(sequence(n - 1) + 3)
    }
  }else{
    stop("n must be stricly positive")
  }
}
sequence(30)
# returns 32770
```